# Sheets formula for sumproduct based on matching criteria across two sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to calculate Average Labor Cost based on staff allocation percentage times labor cost - SUMPRODUCT works beautifully for this when Labor Cost and Allocation % are adjacent to Staff Name in one sheet. But I want to draw the Labor Cost from a separate source sheet.

I've got to be able to use the staff name as the matching criteria so that John Doe, allocation 50% (sheet 1) will be matched up with John Doe, labor cost $25 (sheet 2).

I've tried: QUERY with Join and FILTER - both return the matched labor cost values no problem, but the values aren't ordered for a SUMPRODUCT to work correctly

INDEX/MATCH, of course, works to match the Name with Labor Cost or vice versa.

In Sheet 1, I have Col A: % Allocation, Col B: Staff Name
In Sheet 2, I have Col A: Staff Name, Col B: Cost Rate

Note Staff Name is unordered in both Sheets, and Sheet 1 may contain a subset of names found in Sheet 2

[Sheet1 Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcagk.png)

[image: Sheet1 Structure]

[Sheet 2 Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpefY.png)

[image: Sheet 2 Structure]

If Labor Cost and % Allocation are in the same sheet (on same rows), SUMPRODUCT is a no-brainer and produces the desired result. But I don't want the Labor Cost values to be visible to users of Sheet 1, so...

Can I do the equivalent of SUMPRODUCT by creating a range that is Labor Cost per each staff (from Sheet 2) but that is ordered in the same fashion as Sheet 1 (so that John Doe's labor Cost is the first result in the output, rather than the third result)??

Note: I know I could create a manual Index/Match reference to each record and include it in a sumproduct formula, but I will have dozens of these records throughout the Sheet, so I need a formula that evaluates a range and returns a range.

---

thank you for the follow up - I have recreated the issue in this sheet below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w1pykTcSOn8Jj6Yca5cfVj7ynVAMIXakfBuh6AsOAxM/edit#gid=251477468

I may not have been clear in my first post, but I want to incorporate the Labor Costs associated with each staff by reference into a formula for AVERAGE Labor Cost, but not show the actual labor costs in the DEV sheet.

Comment: Welcome. May I explain why we ask you to share your spreadsheet? Screenshots can be very useful but they don't enable us to recreate your demo data for testing, they don't tell us the layout of data in your spreadsheet (whether on a single sheet or multiple sheets), and they don't enable you to easily demonstrate what a successful outcome would look like. So please would you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue, and, of course, please remove your personal information?

Comment: thank you for the feedback, I have included a link to sheet file

Comment: How's this? `=sumproduct(A7:A9,vlookup(B7:B9,LaborCost!$A$2:$B$6,2,false))` not sure how it can apply in broader, dynamic spreadsheet, byt certainly works in the demo data.

Comment: @tedinoz, Thank you! That works perfectly. A somewhat embarrassingly simple solution I hadn't considered. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reply from Tedinoz worked well
Using this formula
=sumproduct(A7:A9,vlookup(B7:B9,LaborCost!$A$2:$B$6,2,false)